# Magento 2 Admin Grid Create New And Edit Page

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I created a post module and I am trying to create the new and edit admin pages.

I used this [tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html) for the admin grid however the create button and edit functions are not working

I am able to create custom admin pages, however I am sure there must be an easier way.

Code:

Block:

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml;

class Post extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_post';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Mageplaza_HelloWorld';
        $this->_headerText = __('Posts');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Create New Post');
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post" name="mageplaza_post_grid">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="mageplaza_post_grid.grid" as="grid">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
                        <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection</argument>
                        <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                        <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="mageplaza_post_grid.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="post_id">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="name">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="created_at">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">created_at</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="updated_at">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">updated_at</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Posts')));

        return $resultPage;
    }


}
```

Comment: can you please paste code in your question.

Comment: Added the layout, controller and block files